# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:No signature of method --groovy script in soap

Tags: groovy

I have defined the array

```
def sample1 = ["A","B","C","D"] as String[]
..
..
def sample9 = ["555","454","678","456"] as String[]
def p = ["1","2","3","4"] as String[]

for (k=0; k <= 4; k++) {
    setValues(sample1[k].concat(p[k]), sample9[k]) 
}    `
```

I'm trying to get values like:

```
A1 = 555
B2 = 454
```

but on execution I get an error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script7.setValues() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [A1, [555]] Possible solutions: getClass() error at line: XX
```

Could anyone help around? Can we set the values for 1 array with another? If so please help me out on this

Comment: What does the method `setValues` look like? Exception says that there is no signature like `setValues(String s1, String s2)` for this method. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the your lists, transpose them and then create the map with `collectEntries`.  e.g.

```
def sample1 = ["A","B","C","D"]
def sample9 = ["555","454","678","456"]
def p = ["1","2","3","4"]

println([sample1, p, sample9].transpose().collectEntries{ k1, k2, v -> ["${k1}${k2}", v] })
// -> [A1:555, B2:454, C3:678, D4:456]
```

Comment: Thanks on that ....i am able to get the result but it is in a single row ,due to that the values stored is not accessible   i did like     def rest1 = ([sample1, p, sample9].transpose().collectEntries{ k1, k2, v -> ["${k1}${k2}", v] })    i am getting value as expected but when i try to access with index i am not getting the individual value like A1=555

Comment: You can use `rest1["A1"]` -- otherwise please refine the question and update what you actually tried and where it failed.